# Point cloud stitching using ROS

Tags: octomap, ros-kinetic, ardrone

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am utilizing a pair of manually calibrated stereo cameras (so, it's not a standard kinect) for obtaining pointclouds.

Assuming I can obtain the (left) camera's post using an April Tag ,
I would like to know if there is a way to  **stitch together point clouds in ROS, as long as I know the tf transform of the sensor?** (possibly using just command line or launch files ?)
I have seen a few packages (not ROS packages) like [this](https://github.com/ethz-asl/ethzasl_icp_mapping).

I have also seen a few posts on ROS forum (like [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/252632/how-to-correctly-build-an-octomap-using-a-series-of-registered-point-clouds/) but there are no accepted answers)

**My use-case:**
I would like to build an Octomap (from a pair of manually calibrated stereo cameras) from this and then use it for drone motion planning.
Can someone provide any suggestions on where to start ?

Thanks a lot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287557/point-cloud-stitching-using-ros/) by [malharjajoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33038/malharjajoo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2018-04-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe this is what [stereo_image_proc](http://wiki.ros.org/stereo_image_proc) (and friends) was made for.

It may not be the most efficient way to do it, but it could be a start.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [malharjajoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33038/malharjajoo/) on 2018-04-05**:
Hi,  thanks for your answer ... I just want to confirm my understanding, but if I want to map an entire room in 3D, can I just move my stereo camera around (and then somehow register the pointclouds into a single pointcloud) ? I assume this will require me to know the 6D pose of the stereo camera ?

**Comment by [malharjajoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33038/malharjajoo/) on 2018-04-05**:
I would also like to mention that efficiency is not my concern, since I only want to map the room once.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-05**:
Afaik, "registration" of a pointcloud is typically matching RGB values to individual points. I don't believe `stereo_image_proc` does that, but I haven't checked.

**Comment by [malharjajoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33038/malharjajoo/) on 2018-04-05**:
Hi, I guess I am a bit unclear on what "registration" means then. I am looking to "stitch" together a sequence of pointclouds (as shown - [in this matlab example](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/3-d-point-cloud-registration-and-stitching.html)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-05**:
It could just be me misremembering or misunderstanding. Your question sounds more like a mapping one than a simple case of stereo matching and point cloud conversion.

Perhaps [rtabmap_ros](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros) would be better here.

**Comment by [malharjajoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33038/malharjajoo/) on 2018-04-05**:
Hi, thanks, Ill look into it. Just updated the question title as well.